# How to determine time needed to upload data to Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We need to populate database which sits on Amazon WS { EC2 (Compute Cluster Eight extra large)  + EBS 1TB }. Given that we have close to 700GB of data on local, how can I find out the time (theoretical) it would take to upload the entire data? I could not find any information on data upload/download speeds for EC2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this will depend strongly on the networking betweeen your site and amazon's data centre...

1. Test it with a few GB and extrapolate.
2. Be aware of [AWS Import/Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) and consider the option of simply couriering Amazon a portable hard drive.  (Old saying: "Never underestimate the bandwidth of a stationwagon full of tape").  In fact I note the [page](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/) includes a section "When to use..." which gives some indication of transfer times vs. connection bandwidth.

Comment: The problem with interpolation is, that, unless you are using an instance with dedicated fibre connections, amazon reserves a minimum bandwidth available to your vm, depending on machine size. If more bandwidth is available, you will be able to consume more. This will sophisticate your measurements

Comment: @MichelFeldheim: Unless the OP has a *spectacularly* good local internet connection, I'd be far more worried about the limitations and variability of bandwidth *to* Amazon's datacentres than *within* Amazon's datacentres.  (And if I ever was really worried about the latter I note Amazon has specialized high-IO instances available).  But yes, obviously repeating any experiments at different times to investigate the statistics of temporal variations would be a good idea in any scientific approach.